# XSL add new attribute at last position

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to modify an xml tree by xslt:

Add an attribute to a node, but the new attribute should be the lattest one.

Example:

```
<A>
   <B att1="val1" />
</A>
```

Result:

```
<A>
  <B att1="val" newAtt="newValue"/>
</A>
```

By using the following xsl, the attribute newAtt will be placed as **first** attribute of B.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="newAtt">newValue</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well attributes have no order so there is no ensured ordering but you could try

```
<xsl:template match="B">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="newAtt">newValue</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin says, attributes are intrinsically unordered. Though some XSLT processors will retain the order in which attributes are written, you can't rely on this.

Saxon has an option to control the order in which attributes are serialized: see

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/attribute-order